# Dynamic tab width in a Flex 4 TabBar component with skin

Tags: width, flex4, tabbar

I have a Flex 4 TabBar component with a custom skin. In this skin, the item renderer is defined with an ButtonBarButton with a custom skin.
All the tabs in the itemrenderer have now the same width.

The client however wants me to make the tabs width dynamically, so a smaller tab for a smaller label, a bigger one for a long label.
Does anybody know how to adjust the width of Tab (ButtonBarButton)?

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that works.

Create a custom component that inherits from ButtonBarButton, call it CustomTabButton.

Add a **bindable property** *tabWidth*.
Then when we update tabWidth, the width of the tab is adjusted with it.
THis is how you update the skin:

- set the host component to the custom class CustomTabButton.
- In the SparkSkin definition, bind the width value to the hostComponents property tabWidth.

  *width="{hostComponent.tabWidth}"*

The skin looks like this:

```
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                 xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                 xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                 xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
                 minHeight="54"
                 width="{hostComponent.tabWidth}"
                 xmlns:tabbar="be.boulevart.project.components.tabbar.*">

        <!-- host component -->
        <fx:Metadata>
            <![CDATA[ 
            [HostComponent("be.boulevart.project.components.tabbar.CustomTabButton")]
            ]]>
        </fx:Metadata>
```